# Are the anomeric hydroxy groups of α-maltose and β-maltose, axial or equatorial, respectively?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, stereochemistry

This Q&A is a continuation from the following Q&A;
[What do we get when we joint two α- glucoses via an α1,4 bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173745/what-do-we-get-when-we-joint-two-%ce%b1-glucoses-via-an-%ce%b11-4-bond)

**More straightforwardly, the question may focus on whether the bond represented by the following straight line means equatorial or axial　(Find the OH circled in blue in the following figure).**

[image]
https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.388329.html

Above figure is quoted from chemspide. If I understand correctly, the bond or solid line may indicates the anomeric hydroxy group of the alpha-maltose is equatorial, am I right(See the blue circle of the figure, quoted above)?

The chemspide also has figure which may indicates the anomeric hydroxy group of alpha-maltose has axical anomeric hydroxy group, shown as follows. (See the blue circle of the figure, quoted below)

[image]

https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.6019.html

However, Wikipedia has figures which indicate the anomeric hydroxy group of α-maltose is axial and β-maltose has equatorial one.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose

So, I' very confused.

On the other hand, PubChem has following descriptions, quoted below; this article
is titled simply "maltose," but this article also has the description which the  "maltose" is synonymous with the "beta-maltose".

[image]

However, although the article for the α-maltose titled  "α-maltose" but the article also　has the description  which indicate the "α-maltose  is also synonymous with maltose".

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/alpha-Maltose#section=3D-Conformer

If I understand correctly, the structural formulas on PubChem indicates;

- **the anomeric hydroxy group of α-maltose　is axal but　directed Upward**
- **the anomeric hydroxy group of β-maltose　is also axial but directed downward**.

anomeric hydroxy groups of both A and B in this appear to be axial.

[image]
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/alpha-Maltose#section=Structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maltose [4-*O*-(α-D-glucopyranosyl)-D-glucopyranose] always has an α-1-*O*-4 linkage. The bridging oxygen at $\ce{C1}$ is axial. For maltose, there are two anomers. The β-anomer (shown below) has the anomeric hydroxyl equatorial while the α-anomer is axial. These two anomers are interconvertible in aqueous solution.
On the other hand, cellobiose [4-*O*-(β-D-glucopyranosyl)-D-glucopyranose] always has a β-1-*O*-4 linkage. It also exists as α- and β- (shown below) anomers, axial and equatorial, respectively.
[The diagrams are from here. A good read.](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/carbohydrates44.pdf).

[image]

[image]